# Android Studio background color are included in png image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I designed a button in photoshop cs6 and save it as a png image. When try to add it in android studio as an imageView or imageButton it includes the background color. I tried `android:backgroud="@android:color/transparent"` but no luck.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/screenTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#BDBDBD"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttonn1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT : https://github.com/Gamer1989/project/issues/1   You can see the images from here.

Comment: Post image or XML Preview. I think you need to change it in photoshop only.

Comment: in Photoshop,  try "remove background" eraser

Comment: I added my xml code but can't upload image. In photshop my image background looks transparent.

Comment: U are using app:srcCompat= to call the png, but this is special for vectors. For a png u should use android:src=, checkout if this has an effect.

Comment: You probably see the background set by the ImageButton's style.
You can just use an ImageView instead of ImageButton. An ImageView renders your image without button style, and has the same onClick events

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried both but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. If it dont works for u you should consider that there is a issue with ur png. Are u using a importer to add images to ur project? For example Batch Drawable Importer.

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/screenTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#BDBDBD"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonn1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used batch importer but still the same. In photoshop my image background is transparent. There is one layer which is transparent and i add it my button to it. Then save it as png file.

Comment: Ok, u may push ur project to github so we could see the entire code.

Comment: Ok imported your code, but i dont have this issue, i works as expected without background colour. I have Android Studio 3.3.1. Consider that the issue is in ur envoriment.

Comment: Is there a reason that u have all this blank space in your png? In my opinion this is unnecessary, u can make the png just as big as ur button and then probably u will not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means the png file does not have a transparent background. Be sure the referred file does have this feature.
This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HadQ7c8aZXw) teaches how to do it.

Comment: When i open image in photoshop background is not white it is transparent.

Comment: Add the following line at your  ImageView:

android:alpha="0.0"

PS: 0.0 is totally transparent and 1.0 is totally opaque

Comment: This time button completely dissappers

Comment: can not upload image. it says you need 10 reputation

Comment: I use android studio 3.3.2. You can see photoshop image here https://github.com/Gamer1989/project/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

You can open your designed photoshop file into Adobe XD and then select your shapes/button that you wants to export, export those in png format, after that you can copy them into android studio drawable folder and you can use it. No background colour will be included like before.

PNG shapes exported from Photoshop:

[image: shape-photoshop]

Same shapes exported from Adobe XD:

[image: shape-adobe-xd]

Comment: You can post images directly to your answer, otherwise use formatted links